# R starts up with error message

Tags: r, error-handling

I am asking this question out of curiosity. I have noticed that whenever I boot R, the instance starts up with this error message [image]

As you can see, R boots with the error message "object 'a' not found" Is there any reason for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[R reads and executes several files at startup](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Startup.html), most prominently the `~/.Rprofile` file (That is, the file `.Rprofile` in your home directory). Check these files to see if they contain anything weird.

You can quickly check whether `.Rprofile` is the culprit by running R with the `--vanilla` command line argument: this argument prevents the user profile to be read, thus the error should vanish.

Comment: Awesome. Just looked into my Rprofile and found a rogue "a". Mystery solved